# Select a join object, given the association, in order to delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out what the proper way is to delete an association. But it is easier to explain with code:

```
class ClassRoom < ActiveRecord::Base

class ClassJoin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :class_room
  belongs_to :student

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :class_joins
  has_many :class_rooms, :through => :class_joins

# show.html.erb

  <% @student.class_rooms.each do |class_room| %>
    <%= class_room.name %><br/>
    <%= link_to "Remove class", student_class_join_path(@student,class_room.something), :method => :delete %>
  <% end %>
```

How do I select the class_join if I'm just looking at the has_many :through association? Is there an easy way to select it, or do I need to do a find_by_class_room_id_and_student_id (or something like that).

Found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365215/how-can-i-access-a-has-many-through-association-objects-relevant-join-model-wit) but I want to know if these is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <% @student.class_joins.each do |class_join| %>
    <%= class_join.class_room.name %><br/>
    <%= link_to "Remove class", student_class_join_path(@student,class_join), :method => :delete %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah… I thought of that after I posted. But… I want something nicer. :)